# Are all of these Clone Wars books Canon in the current Star Wars lore?

Tags: star-wars, canon, the-clone-wars, disney

I'm trying to figure out which novels are canon and everywhere I go I find different answers even on the subredit for star wars.  The best resource I've found is: https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/3y88kg/list_of_new_star_wars_canon_will_be_continually/

Then I looked on Star Wars wikia and saw all these books that are part of the Clone Wars.  **Are these canon too?** 

`Republic Commando: Hard Contact
Shatterpoint
Equipment (Short story in paperback Shatterpoint)
Legacy of the Jedi
The Cestus Deception
The Hive (eBook)
Republic Commando: Triple Zero
Republic Commando: True Colors
MedStar I: Battle Surgeons
MedStar II: Jedi Healer
Secrets of the Jedi
Jedi Trial
Star Wars: The Clone Wars
Out Foxed (eBook)
Yoda: Dark Rendezvous
Labyrinth of Evil`

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Wars_(books)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the Grand Unified Canonicity question, but those books are no longer canon. They just happen to have taken place during the Clone Wars; they’re not part of *The Clone Wars*.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the ref too!  So do the canon star wars books cover what happens in the TV Series?

Comment: Not really; they cover other stuff.

Comment: damn so the only way to know is to watch the show pretty much ?

Comment: Not quite. There are some novelizations: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(novels). They cover some of the events of the TV series, but other elements might not be canon.